Как правильно указать в аннотации, что метод класса возвращает объект этого класса?
[Python 3.7]
Как правильно указать в аннотации, что метод класса возвращает объект этого класса?
Pylance ругается, что класс не определён.


from typing import Self, -> Self или в кавычках -> "ClassName"

Почему не следует так делать, чем плохи скриншоты (картинки). ===> Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?

from typing import Self

... -> Self

или в кавычках:
... -> "ClassName" 

автор: Alexander Lonberg
